# Need to reroute url /foo/index to index/foo on Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting

I need to reroute a url here. I'm using teh end framework and need to set up some basic static pages here. LIke privacy policy, advertise etc - however the problem is that I need to create a controller for each and every page here. Thats not much of an issue but I was wondering if its possibel for me to set it up so:

```
mysite.com/privacy/index
```

would be rerouted to

```
mysite.com/pages/privacy
```

Might sound like a non issue but would like to know

Answer (score 2):

For every static page, you can add a route for it in your application.ini. For example, for `mysite.com/privacy/index` you can do:

```
resources.router.routes.privacy.route = "/privacy/index"
resources.router.routes.privacy.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.privacy.defaults.controller = pages
resources.router.routes.privacy.defaults.action = privacy
```

More about routing in ZF is in the ZF's [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

From my experience I would **STRONGLY** discourage creating custom routes if not 100% needed (exception be urls with keywords for products or CMS generated pages). We wanted to our ecommerce solution to have nice urls like `/about-us/` instead of `/pages/about-us/`, but it's PITA to add any more features, as you had to add new route for every such thing. We currently have like 25 custom routes. You can never tell what the hack the url is because standard-url like `producer/index` is routed from something like `producers`.

If you still want it, follow Marcin's answer :)